# jtree programmatic multi selection

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree

Is there an ability to select multiple tree nodes in JTree programmatically?
I've set multiselection mode by `tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);`

And all I need - make my application be able to select some nodes programmatically. But I've didn't found the way how to do that. Could anybody give advice how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class TreeWithMultiDiscontiguousSelections {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);
        int treeSelectedRows[] = {3, 1};
        tree.setSelectionRows(treeSelectedRows);
        TreeSelectionListener treeSelectionListener = new TreeSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent treeSelectionEvent) {
                JTree treeSource = (JTree) treeSelectionEvent.getSource();
                System.out.println("Min: " + treeSource.getMinSelectionRow());
                System.out.println("Max: " + treeSource.getMaxSelectionRow());
                System.out.println("Lead: " + treeSource.getLeadSelectionRow());
                System.out.println("Row: " + treeSource.getSelectionRows()[0]);
            }
        };
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(treeSelectionListener);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTree With Multi-Discontiguous selection");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(380, 320));
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private TreeWithMultiDiscontiguousSelections() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See:

- [setSelectionPaths(TreePath[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setSelectionPaths%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%5B%5D%29) and [setSelectionRows(int[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setSelectionRows%28int%5B%5D%29) in the [JTree JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html).
- [How to Use Trees](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Pasting into the world-with-arrow dialog escapes the brackets, and it reorders the links.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your JTree

```
tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.CONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);
```