# Jtree get object based on mouse click?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtree

I use this code fragment to perform some action on a tree when the mouse is double-clicked: open a window and get the `node` which was double clicked by the mouse, but it doesn't return anything, it returns null:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int selRow = contactTree.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        TreePath selPath = contactTree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        System.out.println(contactTree.getEditingPath());
        Account memberToChat;
        if(selRow != -1) {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {

            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                new ChatWindow().setVisible(true);
                memberToChat=(Account)node.getUserObject(); // node is declared somewhere in the class as   DefaultMutableTreeNode node
                System.out.println(memberToChat.getFirstName()+" "+memberToChat.getEmail());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: node is "declared", fine.  But where is it set to the current selection?  Also you mention "returns null". Where is that return statement?  You should clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [for JTree to set proper setSelectionMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select)
- add [TreeSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html)
- example with [TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6985736/714968)